# php read from text file and combine duplicate entries

Tags: php, html, arrays, fopen, fwrite

I have this little piece of code I'm just testing out that basically redirects a user if their IP doesn't match the predefined IP and if it doesn't match write that IP into a text file.

```
$file = fopen("ips.txt", "w");

if ($ip == "iphere") {
    echo "Welcome";
    fclose($file);
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    fwrite($file, "\n" . $ip);
    if ($file) {
        $array = explode("\n", fread($file, filesize("ips.txt")));
    }

    $result = print_r($array, TRUE);

    fclose($file);
}
```

What I want to do is take the IPs that I'm writing to the text file, put them all into an array to find the duplicates, make note of the duplicates, filter them out, then write them back into that file or another txt file, but I'm stuck and not sure where to go from here.

Comment: why don't you check for duplicates first, then write to it if it isn't in the file? strpos or stripos can work with this. But there are other ways/functions for this also.

Comment: If you change how you are processing the IP addresses you won't have to worry about duplication.

Comment: So you just want to make sure, that you don't write an IP twice into the file ?

Comment: I want to write duplicate IPs into the file to see the frequency of the attempt to access to page but I don't want to have to consistently run a query to see how many duplicates there are, I would like all the duplicates combined with some sort of identifier next to the entry ie ip1 X2 ip2 X4... etc

Comment: why don't you use a database for this? a lot simpler, and a lot less trouble.

Comment: To elaborate, duplicate IPs are a good thing and I want them written into the file except rather than taking up 10 lines I want it to take up 1 line with some sort of counter... if the post was confusing

Comment: that file stands at growing rather large. I suggest against it. A database is the solution here.

Comment: A database would be much easier, yes but I'm trying to learn more by trying some different things albeit not the most efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest you use serialize or json_encode to store the ip's in a file , that way you could add more info (how many times an IP has visited, last visit, etc.).

I'll show you a simple example.

1: Create some dummy ips for test.

```
$IPs = array(
'192.168.0.1' => array(
  'visits' => 23,
  'last'   => '2015-07-20'
),
'192.168.0.2' => array(
  'visits' => 32,
  'last'   => '2015-06-23'
)
);
```

So here we created an associative array with 2 IP addreses, that also contain visit count and last visit.

Save the file using php serialize function or json_encode (i prefer json format, because it can be used by other languages).

```
$for_save = json_encode($IPs); // OR serialize($IPs)
file_put_contents("FILE_NAME",$for_save); //Save the file with the IP's
```

Now its time to read the file

```
$file = fopen("FILE_NAME", "w");
$file = json_decode($file) // or unserialize($file);
```

and now we have the array to use as we wish and we can search for ip's using php array functions, and offcourse modify information about ips :

```
if(array_key_exists("YOUR_IP_HERE",$file)){
 //What to do if we have found the ip in the file, for example : 
   $file['YOUR_IP']['visits']++; //we add +1 visit for that ip
}
```

And now we can save the file again

```
$file = json_encode($file);
file_put_contents("IP_FILE_NAME",$file);
```

Comment: This is excellent thanks!

Comment: This is a really good and well-explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with this approach, around threading and performance.   What happens if two people hit the webpage and write to the same file at the same time?  Also, this file can grow to an unbounded size?  This will be slow.  You don't need to manually check all ip's, only that one exists.

It might be better to use a database table for this.  Otherwise, you'll need to handle filelocking as well.

psuedo code for function check_ips:

Select * from ips where ip =?.  Check the user id

if no result, insert the ip.  it's unknown.  (also if needed you can add constraint to the table to prevent duplicate ip's)

otherwise, the ip is known

You can log counts, dates, last access, or other stats in the table as a calculated summary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easly reading the file with the ip in an array and the get the `unique`  value from the array like this

```
$ipList = file(ips.txt);

$ipUnique = array_unique($ipList);
```

then yo can save or parse the $ipUnique for your porpose.